# Pass Java List to SQL query Grails

Tags: sql, list, grails

i have a populated list:

```
def someList=... (string values)
```

and I want to pass this into a SQL statement to restrict which columns the query selects.

```
db.rows("select ${someList} from arch_application")
```

However, I get this error when I try to do so:

```
There is a ? parameter in the select list. This is not allowed.
```

Anyone have an ideas? Thanks!

Comment: I have not understand. Whith db.rows you are doing a jdbc query with the datasource? Or are you using hql or what?

Answer (score 0):

When you pass a GString to [`Sql.rows`](http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/groovy/sql/Sql.html#rows%28groovy.lang.GString%29), it gets parsed differently than normal in groovy.  In particular, it creates a PreparedStatement with replaceable parameters for `${}` substitutions.  In your case this is probably not what you want.  Try forcing the GString to a Java string:

```
db.rows("select ${someList.join(',')} from arch_application" as String)
```